# Filter dynamically generated Options from $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out why I can't filter the content of the select when dynamically generated from an `$http`. In the plunker provided I can filter when I provide a test dataset, but when I retrieve the data from an $http request the select does not filter.

http://plnkr.co/edit/lmBRIvfZQogS4LTx2FYV?p=preview

Here is my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('http://graph.facebook.com/4')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.dataset = data;
      })
      .error(function() {
          console.log('My name is Error, now eat it!');
      });

    // TEST DATASET
    // $scope.dataset = [
    //   {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
    //   {name:'white', shade:'light'},
    //   {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
    //   {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
    //   {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
    // ];

});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  Search:
  <input type="search" ng-model="searchText" />


  <BR>
  <BR>

  <select>
    <option ng-repeat="data in dataset | filter: searchText">{{data}}</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter filters on items in an array. What is being returned from the service is a single object

`{ "id": "4", "name": "Mark Zuckerberg", "first_name": "Mark", "last_name": "Zuckerberg", "link": "http://www.facebook.com/zuck", "username": "zuck", "gender": "male", "locale": "en_US" }`

This is coming in dropdown because the dropdown also support object properties i think.

Comment: Is there any way to filter on an object?

Comment: I am not sure about that

Comment: How about easily converting an object to an array?

Comment: This plunker shows how I achieved converting and object to array for my purposes, thanks for the clarification.

http://plnkr.co/edit/9M3zZFN5jyV8w7fg7EE3?p=preview